# How to make circle in go using gorethinkdb's geospatial commands

Tags: go, rethinkdb

How to write the following code in go using [gorethinkdb](https://github.com/dancannon/gorethink)

```
r.circle([-117.220406,32.719464], 10, {:unit => 'mi'})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, you can use [r.Circle](https://godoc.org/github.com/dancannon/gorethink#Circle) as follows:

```
import r "gopkg.in/dancannon/gorethink.v2"
...

r.Circle(r.Point(-117.220406, 32.719464), r.Expr(10), r.CircleOpts{Unit: "mi"})
```

You can check out more examples directly from the [documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/dancannon/gorethink)